# Segmentation fault error when installing libraries with Composer

Tags: php, aws-lambda, composer-php

Over the last few days I have been trying to compile PHP to use it in Amazon Lambda, but my experience has been poor, to say the least.

I'm following a tutorial, and it was working great until the moment I needed to install three Composer libraries.

Here's what's happening.

I launched a t2.medium instance (2 vCPU and 4 GB) on Amazon EC2, using the Amazon Linux 2023 AMI.

Once I connected to the instance, I ran the following commands:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install autoconf bison gcc gcc-c++ libcurl-devel libxml2-devel -y

curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
sudo ./aws/install
sudo yum group install 'Development Tools' -y
sudo yum install perl-core zlib-devel -y

cd /usr/local/src/
sudo wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz
sudo tar -xf openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2u
cd /usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.2u
sudo ./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl shared zlib
sudo make
sudo make install

cd ~
mkdir ~/php-8.2.6-source
curl -sL https://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.2.6.tar.gz | tar -xvz
cd ~/php-8.2.6/
./buildconf --force
sudo yum install oniguruma-devel -y
sudo yum install sqlite-devel -y
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig/" ./configure --prefix=/home/ec2-user/php-8.2.6-source --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-curl --with-mysqli --enable-mbstring --enable-soap
sudo make install

mkdir -p ~/lambda-root/{bin,src,lib}/
cd ~/lambda-root
touch ./bootstrap
chmod +x ./bootstrap
cp ~/php-8.2.6-source/bin/php ./bin
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | ./bin/php
./bin/php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle
./bin/php composer.phar require aws/aws-sdk-php
./bin/php composer.phar require phpzip/phpzip
```

My problem is in the last three commands. Whenever I run any of the three `./bin/php composer.phar require [ . . . ]``the command shows an error.

Here is the output when I run the command
`./bin/php composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle -vvv`:

```
Running 2.6.6 (2023-12-08 18:32:26) with PHP 8.2.6 on Linux / 6.1.66-91.160.amzn2023.x86_64
Reading ./composer.json (/home/ec2-user/lambda-root/composer.json)
Loading config file ./composer.json (/home/ec2-user/lambda-root/composer.json)
Checked CA file /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem: valid
Executing command (/home/ec2-user/lambda-root): 'git' 'branch' '-a' '--no-color' '--no-abbrev' '-v'
Executing command (/home/ec2-user/lambda-root): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git --version
Executing command (/home/ec2-user/lambda-root): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (/home/ec2-user/lambda-root): hg branch
Executing command (/home/ec2-user/lambda-root): fossil branch list
Executing command (/home/ec2-user/lambda-root): fossil tag list
Executing command (/home/ec2-user/lambda-root): svn info --xml
Reading /home/ec2-user/.config/composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/ec2-user/.config/composer/composer.json (/home/ec2-user/.config/composer/composer.json)
Downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Previously the output was also showing the message `Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/ec2-user/.config/composer/composer.json` right before downloading the packages, so I created the file `/home/ec2-user/.config/composer/composer.json`.

This is the content of the file.:

```
{
   "require": {}
}
```

Would anyone happen to have any idea why this error is happening and how to fix it? Obviously, in the video it works without any problems. A classic case of "it works on my machine".

I tried using the memory_limit argument, changing the command to:

```
./bin/php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

But the result is exactly the same.

I also tried with the COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT argument:

```
./bin/php composer.phar COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

This time a message appeared saying `Command "COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1" is not defined.`.

Comment: Why do you need to run `composer require` on any remote system?

Comment: Also, why do you need to compile PHP on your own? Why not use any existing build?

Answer (score -1):

First off, you should have provided the URL for the tutorial you were following - we have no idea what advice it gave you.

Secondly, v 8.2.6 is rather old - although I appreciate that sticking with the version shown in the tutorial *should* have avioided unexpected surprises.

Thirdly, as a programmer, you should have a basic understand of how programs execute in the operating systems you use and some knowledge of diagnosing issues. For the PHP runtime to SEGFAULT, the problem is not in the code you are running (composer) but in the PHP binary or a .so file loaded at runtime. Diagnosing the fault is fairly straightforward - and all the tools required are easily available, but since you didn't know how to do this, it's unlikely you'll be able to identify the actual root cause, never mind fix it.

The fault seems to be ocurring when the command is retrieving content across the internet. So a more useful use of your time might be to write some simple PHP which downloads a file and try that out to see if you can reproduce the fault - then you might experiment further with DNS queries, TCP handshakes, http requests then https connections.

Whether you AWS instance is actually able to connect to the internet at all may depend on some complex configuration - you should also test out these component steps outside of PHP from the command line using dig, nc, curl etc.